# What are the "tag" and "deployment" events in drone

Tags: drone.io

Drone events support `"push", "pull_request", "tag", "deployment"`

https://github.com/drone/drone-yaml-v1/blob/1c89a78f3ae4c8c70114203034a81fec59474bc2/main.go#L30

I have two questions:
When `tag` and `deployment` will be trigger?
who will trigger it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag` events are triggered when you tag a commit (for instance, via the Releases page of your Github repo).

`deployment` events can be triggered via the [Github Deployments API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/).

Both are ways for you to control when exactly a new version of your code is (build and) deployed.
For example, a common pattern is to always automatically deploy changes to your master branch to your dev environment and only deploy a tagged version to production (using the aforementioned Github releases or Deployments API).

Comment: thanks a million again. Would like to know how to trigger these events using drone or jenkins plugin